# Android gradle nested multi project dependency issues

Tags: android, gradle, nested, dependencies

Well, I am new to Gradle world. And for this specific issue of mine, I have traversed StackOverflow threads extensively without no avail. In short, what I want is -

Suppose I have 3 projects namely - A(library project), B(library project), C

1. Project A is simple witout no dependencies.
2. Project B is dependent on project A
3. Project C is dependent on project B

So in B's settings.graddle file -

```
include ':ProjA'
project(':ProjA').projectDir = new File('ProjADirectory')
```

And in B's main module's build file-

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':ProjA')
}
And everything works fine for B.
```

However, when I did similar for proj C (adding B as dependant) it tells me that ":ProjA" is not found. I understand that If I add ":ProjA" in C's setting file, it will compile ok.

But I want the script to automatically resolve ":ProjA" since B is added as a dependency. Is it possible, somehow?